# How do we stand on allowing opinions in answers?

Tags: support

I ran into [this edit](https://unix.stackexchange.com/revisions/518000/2):

> Side note: (hopefully I don't get flak for this) Mint is not a distribution. It is built on top of Ubuntu. This is not a very good practice. Other projects are flavors of Ubuntu, but mint tries to be a new distribution built on top of it. This is prone to providing various bad experiences, and mint has a history of security issues due to the nature of the project. I suggest abandoning mint for a real distribution (one that is actually in charge of what is happening to it) Debian, Fedora, Arch, and Void are all great Linux distributions. Thank you for indulging me;)

and tried to leave [a welcoming comment](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/425418/linux-mint-cinnamon-high-ram-usage/518000#comment957100_518000) and the OP did edit [their answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/518000/90054) **but** it's till too opinionated *in my humble opinion* and doesn't have enough body to make it a real answer, so asking the more experienced users here:

*What should I do about this answer?*

Comment: Original post is deleted now, I think. "Page not found". :(

Comment: Linux Mint is considered insecure? Is this true?

Comment: You've reached the site that talks about the site @Benjamin so here we talk about *getting rid of bad opinions*...  **;-)**

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just downvote it. You feel this answer isn't useful, that's exactly what downvotes are for. It already has a delete vote and will probably be deleted soon since, as you point out, it doesn't give an answer to the question and instead only an opinion on a pretty much unrelated subject.

But the general answer to "what do I do if I consider an answer bad but not flaggable" is: downvote.

Comment: Downvoting hurts!  Especially at that level of rep.  *But I'll bow to the wisdom of my betters!*  **;-)**